# MongoDB Container Dockerfile no reachable servers

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build an easy Dockerfile to Copy files from current directory into container then run a mongorestore command to seed the data. I've looked at many different websites and I'm still getting the following error.

> 2016-08-17T03:03:22.639+0000    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
>   The command '/bin/sh -c mongorestore --drop /mongo-seed/mongo-seed-data/mongo-dump --host 127.0.0.1:27017' returned a non-zero code: 1

When I "bash" into the container and run the mongorestore command with the same parameters it populates database. I'm at a loss, please help.

Below is the Dockerfile

```
FROM mongo

COPY . /mongo-seed
EXPOSE 27017


CMD ["mongod"]
RUN mongorestore --drop /mongo-seed/mongo-seed-data/mongo-dump --host 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CMD` is run when you start up the container.
So `mongod` is not running when docker executes the last `RUN` instruction of your dockerfile while building the image.

```
FROM mongo
COPY . /mongo-seed
# EXPOSE 27017 //not necessary, the mongo base image already has that instruction
ENTRYPOINT mongod
```

Build and run: `docker build -t foo . && docker run -d --name bar foo`

Execute the `mongorestore` command:

```
docker exec bar mongorestore --drop ...
```

Comment: Everything worked as expected. Needed to use mongorestore instead of mongostore. I'm still learning the different uses for CMD, ENTRYPOINT, RUN, etc.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my end :)